# Order accepts_nested_attributes_for lines

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a accepts_nested_attributes_for association between timesheet and timesheetlines. This works great, but when I want to output the timesheetlines, the lines gets ordered on the ID of the timesheetline record. Instead, I want to order the lines on the "daynr" field. How can I achieve this? The code is like this:

```
<% for timesheetline in timesheet.tms_timesheetlines %>
  <%= timesheetline.daynr %>
  <%= timesheetline.description %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
<% for timesheetline in timesheet.tms_timesheetlines.order(:daynr) %>
```